# How to I include all files from inside a directory in jinja2?

Tags: jinja2

A normal jinja2 include looks like `{% include 'directory/filename.html' %}` but I am looking to do something like `{% include 'dropins/*.html' % where obviously the order would be alphabetically.

Is this possible? How?

Answer (score 6):

You could pass a list of file names, then iterate over them:

```
{% for file_name in file_list %}
    {% include file_name %}
{% endfor %}
```

And of course, inside file_list you should have already built your list of file names

```
file_list = ['dropins/file1.html', 'dropins/file2.html']
```

In Python, I would write some function that could discover all files inside that directory and then save their filenames to the list... or if you know the list just hard code them like above

Comment: This limitation is unfortunate.

Answer (score 0):

To make it more dynamic as compared to Quentin's answer:
Pass the files as an argument to the template. 
---app.py---

```
files = os.listdir(<folder>)
return render_template('index.html', files = files)
```

And iteration can be done in the same way 
---index.html---

```
{% for file in files %}
---code---
{% endfor %}
```